# Oracle SQL: what is the cleanest way to refactor WITH...SELECT... into a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-function

So I have been trying to find the best way to re-write a large chunk of SQL in plan script, in form of

```
WITH
A AS (...<SUB_QA>...),
B AS (...<SUB_QB>...),
C AS (...<SUB_QC>...),
...

SELECT ... FROM
A 
LEFT JOIN B 
LEFT JOIN C
LEFT JOIN ...
ON ....
```

into a FUNCTION. This is mainly to facilitate the reuse the same logic represented by that big chunk in multiple places.

- Contraint 1: can only use RECORD instead of creating customized TYPE;
- Contraint 2: have to keep the content of the those subqueries (e.g.
  , etc) under WITH clause as they are, since each is
  considerably complex.

So far, I only came up with the following, as a simplified example.

- It involves putting the WITH clause in the cursor loop
- **But does it run the WITH clause in each loop, which would be a big worry in term of performance?** When written in function form, and when I run it with SqlDeveloper's 'Explain Plan' function, it doesn't reveal much helpful information at all.
- **Is there better/cleaner/more performant way to do this?**

SQL to create data:

```
--------PERSON table------------
DROP TABLE Test_Persons;
CREATE TABLE Test_Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar2(255),
    FirstName varchar2(255)
);

INSERT INTO Test_Persons
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(1,'LN_1','FN_1');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(2,'LN_2','FN_2');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(3,'LN_21','FN_2');

--------Salary table------------
DROP TABLE TEST_SALARY_A;
CREATE TABLE TEST_SALARY_A ( -- no 'OR REPLACE' for ORACLE
    SalaryID int,
    PersonID int,
    Amount int,
    Tax int,
    Bank varchar2(20)
);

INSERT INTO TEST_SALARY_A
    (SalaryID, PersonID, Amount, Tax, Bank)
    VALUES
    (1, 1, 1000, 300, 'BOA1');

INSERT INTO TEST_SALARY_A
    (SalaryID, PersonID, Amount, Tax, Bank)
    VALUES
    (2, 2, 2000, 600, 'JP1');

INSERT INTO TEST_SALARY_A
    (SalaryID, PersonID, Amount, Tax, Bank)
    VALUES
    (3, 3, 3000, 900, 'TD1');

--------Address table------------
DROP TABLE TEST_ADDRESS_A;
CREATE TABLE TEST_ADDRESS_A ( 
    AddressID int,
    PersonID int,
    Address varchar2(255)
);

INSERT INTO TEST_ADDRESS_A
    (AddressID, PersonID, Address)
    VALUES
    (1, 1, 'address1');

INSERT INTO TEST_ADDRESS_A
    (AddressID, PersonID, Address)
    VALUES
    (2, 2, 'address2');

INSERT INTO TEST_ADDRESS_A
    (AddressID, PersonID, Address)
    VALUES
    (3, 3, 'address3');

commit;
```

Original SQL in Chunk:

```
------------------Original--------------------
WITH 
TEST_JOINED_1 AS (
    SELECT
        tps.PERSONID,
        tps.LASTNAME,
        tsd.ADDRESS
    FROM TEST_PERSONS tps
    LEFT JOIN TEST_ADDRESS_A tsd ON tps.personid = tsd.personid WHERE tps.LASTNAME = 'LN_1'
),
TEST_JOINED_2 AS (
    SELECT
        tps.PERSONID,
        tsl.BANK,
        tsl.TAX
    FROM TEST_PERSONS tps
    LEFT JOIN TEST_SALARY_A tsl ON tps.personid = tsl.personid WHERE tps.LASTNAME = 'LN_1'
)

SELECT tj1.PERSONID as tj1_ID, tj1.LASTNAME, tj1.ADDRESS, tj2.PERSONID as tj2_ID, tj2.BANK, tj2.TAX
  FROM TEST_JOINED_1 tj1
  LEFT JOIN TEST_JOINED_2 tj2 ON tj1.PERSONID = tj2.PERSONID
WHERE tj1.LASTNAME = 'LN_1';
```

Rewrite in FUNCTION:

```
------------------Rewritten in functions with ------------------
------------------Contraint 1: can only use RECORD instead of creating customized TYPE;------------
------------------Contraint 2: have to keep the content of the two subqueries under WITH clause exactly as it is --------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3 AS

    TYPE join_record_type IS RECORD(
      PersonID1 int,
      LastName varchar2(255),
      Address varchar2(255),
      PersonID2 int,
      Bank varchar2(20),
      Tax   int
    );

    TYPE join_record_table_type IS TABLE OF join_record_type;

    FUNCTION get_joined_data(last_name VARCHAR2)
        RETURN join_record_table_type
        PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3 AS

    FUNCTION get_joined_data(last_name VARCHAR2)
        RETURN join_record_table_type
        PIPELINED 
        AS

        join_record join_record_type;

        BEGIN
            FOR x IN (
                -------------------start - WITH clause -- does this run for every RECORD x in the loop??? -----------------------
                WITH 
                TEST_JOINED_1 AS (
                    SELECT
                        tps.PERSONID,
                        tps.LASTNAME,
                        tsd.ADDRESS
                    FROM TEST_PERSONS tps
                    LEFT JOIN TEST_ADDRESS_A tsd ON tps.personid = tsd.personid WHERE tps.LASTNAME = last_name

                ),
                TEST_JOINED_2 AS (
                    SELECT
                        tps.PERSONID,
                        tsl.BANK,
                        tsl.TAX
                    FROM TEST_PERSONS tps
                    LEFT JOIN TEST_SALARY_A tsl ON tps.personid = tsl.personid WHERE tps.LASTNAME = last_name
                )
                -------------------end - WITH clause -------------------

                -------------------start - main select-----------------------
                SELECT tj1.PERSONID as tj1_ID, tj1.LASTNAME, tj1.ADDRESS, tj2.PERSONID as tj2_ID, tj2.BANK, tj2.TAX
                  FROM TEST_JOINED_1 tj1
                  LEFT JOIN TEST_JOINED_2 tj2 ON tj1.PERSONID = tj2.PERSONID
                WHERE tj1.LASTNAME = last_name
                -------------------end - main select--------------------------             
             )
          LOOP
            SELECT x.tj1_ID, x.LASTNAME, x.ADDRESS, x.tj2_ID, x.BANK, x.TAX
                INTO join_record
                FROM DUAL;
            PIPE ROW (join_record);
          END LOOP;
        END;
END; -- END of CREATE
/

select * from table(MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3.get_joined_data('LN_1'));
```

**EDITED: modified example code to have variable in the WITH clause**

```
----------------------Create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE -------------------------
DROP TABLE my_global_temp_table;
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_global_temp_table (
      PersonID int,
      LastName varchar2(255),
      Address varchar2(255),
      Bank varchar2(20)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

----------------------Create PACKAGE AND FUNCTION -------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3 AS

    TYPE join_record_type IS RECORD(
      PersonID int,
      LastName varchar2(255),
      Address varchar2(255),
      Bank varchar2(20)
    );

    TYPE join_record_table_type IS TABLE OF join_record_type;

    FUNCTION get_joined_data(last_name VARCHAR2)
        RETURN join_record_table_type
        PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3 AS


    FUNCTION get_joined_data(last_name VARCHAR2)
        RETURN join_record_table_type
        PIPELINED 
        AS

        join_record join_record_type;

        BEGIN
            --------------------use GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE-------------------------
            INSERT INTO my_global_temp_table
                    -------------------start - WITH ... SELECT ... clause -- does this run for every RECORD x in the loop??? -----------------------
                    WITH 
                    TEST_JOINED_1 AS (
                        SELECT
                            tps.PERSONID,
                            tps.LASTNAME,
                            tsd.ADDRESS
                        FROM TEST_PERSONS tps
                        LEFT JOIN TEST_ADDRESS_A tsd ON tps.personid = tsd.personid
                        WHERE tps.LASTNAME = last_name
                    )
                    SELECT tj1.PERSONID, tj1.LASTNAME, tj1.ADDRESS, ts.BANK
                      FROM TEST_JOINED_1 tj1
                      LEFT JOIN TEST_SALARY_A ts ON tj1.PERSONID = ts.PERSONID
                    WHERE tj1.LASTNAME = last_name;
                    -------------------end - WITH ... SELECT ... clause --         

            FOR x IN (
                SELECT * FROM my_global_temp_table
            )
            LOOP
                SELECT x.PERSONID, x.LASTNAME, x.ADDRESS, x.BANK
                    INTO join_record
                    FROM DUAL;
                PIPE ROW (join_record);
            END LOOP;
        END;
END; -- END of CREATE
/

--------------------Call the FUNCTION-------------------------
select * from table(MY_JOIN_TEST_SP_PACKAGE_3.get_joined_data('LN_1'));
```

**EDITED: following @Littefoot suggestion, try out using CREATE GLOBAL TEMP table but giving out '17/21     PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression'. I am not sure why?**

**EDITED: Corrected the Insert syntax, but will get error 'ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query', I believe that this is because I called the function that contains that Insert from a SELECT**

Comment: Does anyone know how exactly I can find out if I have the WITH clause within the loop as above (which also uses a variable), if it is 'get called' in every loop hence the heavy performance impact??? Tried to use SqlDeveloper 'Explain Plan' but not working.

Comment: Main point here is to move the 'WITH ... SELECT ...' clause out side of the FOR statement but still keep it in the FUNCTION. So far not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using variables and other pl sql constructs, I would suggest you break with clauses in the form of a table or materialize view. In this way you don't need to take risk of rewriting the logic of query in pl sql block and missing something.
I would suggest using materialize view advantage of materialize view over the table is that you don't need to drop table next time you load data and also you can use nologging with materialized view.No logging makes it very fast.
It will be very fast and have minimum risk.

Thanks
Bhanu Yadav

Comment: in fact, in reality, I do have the variable in the WITH clause, just edited the sample code to reflect that.

Comment: I see u are using  tj1.LASTNAME = last_name as a parameter, in that case, if possible create a table in which u can maintain last name and you can pass data through view. Its one of the approach I can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As there's nothing *dynamic* in the `WITH` factoring clause (i.e. you don't use variables - at least, I didn't notice any), I'd suggest you to create a **view** (based on that `WITH`) and use it whenever needed.

If the real query is really complex and takes time to execute, you could create a global temporary table (`GTT`), most probably choosing to keep its data during the session (`ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`) properly index it and store view (or `WITH`'s) contents in there. Then you'd use the `GTT` in your code

Although, Oracle will keep date returned by a query in memory so you might even have to really "execute" it once, but the memory isn't unlimited so ... test it, compare results you get, pick the one that seems to be the best.

To me, the `GTT` idea sounds promising, but without actual information it is difficult to decide.

**[EDIT, about GTT]**

Oracle's "Global temporary table" is, actually, "local" from your point if view (note that, if you're on 18c (I don't think you are, though) you can create a *private* temporary table). You create it once, using the `create global temporary table ...`. Data you insert into it is visible ONLY to you, nobody else; it is restricted to your own transaction (if it is created with the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`) or session (`ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`). Pick the one that suits you best.

What does it mean? It means that you'd create the GTT once, providing column list and their datatypes. Every user, that uses your procedure, would insert its own data set into it (you'd use a query with the LAST NAME parameter, as you said) and use it throughout the transaction (or session). Many users can do that at the same time, but - as I've said - everyone would see only its own data.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
-- create table once. Do NOT create it, drop it, create again tomorrow, drop ... 
-- Create it once, use it many times.
create global temporary table gtt_my_data
  (id        number,
   c_name    varchar2(20), ...
  )
on commit preserve rows;

create index i1_gmd_id on gtt_my_data (id);

-- your procedure
procedure p_myproc (par_last_name in varchar2) is
begin
  insert into gtt_my_data (id, c_name, ...)
    select id, c_name, ...
    from some_table join some_other_table ...
    where some_table.last_name = par_last_name;

  -- now, do whatever you do. When you need to fetch data from the GTT, do so
  select ... into ...
    from table_x join gtt_my_data on ...

  update ... set some_column = (select another_column
                                from table_y join gtt_my_data on ...
                               )

end;
```

Once you're done: if you end the session, data will be *removed* from the GTT. If you want, you can do it manually (either delete or truncate its contents).

**[EDIT #2: INSERT INTO A GTT]**

Insert is wrong; you don't insert `values`, but something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_global_temp_table
  WITH test_joined_1 AS 
    (SELECT tps.personid,
            tps.lastname,
            tsd.address
       FROM test_persons tps
       LEFT JOIN test_address_a tsd ON tps.personid = tsd.personid
       WHERE tps.lastname = last_name
    )
  SELECT tj1.personid,
         tj1.lastname,
         tj1.address,
         ts.bank
  FROM test_joined_1 tj1
  LEFT JOIN test_salary_a ts ON tj1.personid = ts.personid
  WHERE tj1.lastname = last_name;
```

Simplified, on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> create table test (empno number, deptno number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (empno, deptno)
  2  with temp as
  3    (select empno, deptno from emp)
  4  select t.empno, t.deptno
  5  from temp t join dept d on d.deptno = t.deptno
  6  where d.deptno = 10;

3 rows created.

SQL>
```

Comment: in fact, in reality, I do have the variable in the WITH clause, just edited the sample code to reflect that; 

Two problem about using GTT in my case: 
1. I may need temporary table, but not GLOBAL in this case, but local to my Function, yet I hope to move the logic of creating it outside of the Loop

Comment: 2. since I have a variable to the selection (lastname) in my case now, can I create GTT incorporating such variable? @Littlefoot: Could you edit your response to show some sample code?

Comment: I added some more info; have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, I edited the original post to use the GTT but got some compilation error that I couldn't figure out. Pls have a look above.

Comment: Have a look at EDIT #2.

Comment: Ok, this is tedious. after I corrected my insert logic it gives me error 'ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query', I believe that this is because I called the function that contains that Insert from a SELECT? that is a bit more restrictive than expected.

Comment: all and all, I couldn't help wondering why it needs to be so hard to achieve something relatively trivial -- I just want a 'table-ish' variable (ideally local to my function) to hold onto the value from 'WITH ... SELECT ...'

Comment: Right; you can't INSERT in a function you call with a SELECT. I missed that, sorry. Huh, what now? Put INSERT into a procedure and call it first. Then call the function.